# UIToolbar in a popover

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

Is it possible to show toolbar items in a UIViewController inside a popover? I'm doing this in the viewDidLoad method of my view controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:nil action:nil];
    [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:addButton]];
    [addButton release];
```

Then I'm wrapping this view controller in a `UINavigationController` (which has a `toolbar` property, and according to the docs, I'm supposed to use the `setToolbarItems` method of `UIViewController` to add items to the toolbar), then presenting it in a popover.

I do not see the toolbar. Are toolbars unsupported when using a popover?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out, apparently the toolbar is hidden by default so you have to do this:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

To make it appear.

Comment: well, it works :) but I can't seem to add buttons to it. will probably figure it out soon. thanks again.

Comment: A kind person just answered that one for me:  The buttons are added to the view displayed in the popover. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853038/how-do-i-add-buttons-to-a-toolbar-within-an-ipad-popover[/link]