# How do I add buttons to a toolbar within an iPad popover?

Tags: ios, sdk, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, popover

Hoping someone here has conquered this one 'cuz it's driving me crazy.  My app includes a popover that is used to enter and edit information.  I learned today that it's possible to show a toolbar at the bottom of the popover and that's great -- except that I cannot for the life of me get any buttons to show on said toolbar.  Here's where we start:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: editorViewer];
//*** This makes the toolbar visible
[navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
//*** Create a 'trash' button
UIBarButtonItem *trashButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target: nil action: @selector(deleteItem)]; 
//*** Create an array of buttons
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: trashButton, nil];
```

I've tried each of the following to add the button, with no success:

```
navigationController.toolbar.items = buttons;
```

and

```
[navigationController setToolbarItems: buttons]
```

and

```
[navigationController.toolbar setItems: buttons animated: NO];
```

I get a pretty little toolbar, no buttons.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you do set the toolbar hidden state on the navigation controller, the tool bar items are taken from the navigation controller's top view controller's toolbarItems property.

In your case

```
editorView.toolbarItems = buttons;
```

or

```
[editorView setToolbarItems:buttons];
```

while

```
[navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

remains the same.

Comment: Bless you!  You've made my day!  In considering other places where I've used toolbars, it makes sense, even though it's counterintuitive on the face of it.  Mark